# The correct way to deploy artifact from nexus

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying to build and CI environment and I think that it works because I can publish a jar into Nexus automatically.

```
Git
BitBucket
Jenkins
Nexus OSS
```

I am looking information about the deployment of maven projects automatically when it publish to nexus , but I am not sure about my initial idea.

My initial idea is to download the latest artifact from Nexus3 and use mvn spring-boot:run but I am not sure about my decission.

I read information about Puppet but I am not sure about this option, could anyone help to me about this process ? Or send to me another link in the StackOVerflow about this problem.

Regards !

Comment: You'd be better off packaging your application as a Docker image and setting up an [image stream](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/architecture/core_concepts/builds_and_image_streams.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I have basic knowledge about Docker but it is necessary for this ? In the moment that I have two artifacts in nexus with Docker how it works with CD(Continuous delivery) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a pipeline in Jenkins:

- First job builds an artifacts and uploads it to the storage (in your case it's Nexus). It has to determine which version it uploaded - the easiest way to do that is to set the version by the job itself and then upload the known version (see a sample script at the bottom).
- Then pass the known version to the downstream jobs (like deploying to envs). You'd need to tell Jenkins which version you just deployed - it's possible to write it into a key-value file and then use something like EnvInject plugin to read it as an env var.
- To download an artifact from Nexus use wget/curl:

  `http://nexus.domain/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r={repository}&g={groupId}&a={artifactId}&v={version}&p={type}`
- Jenkins has several plugins for building pipelines, but you can start with a simple built-in possibility of jobs to invoke other jobs.

Couple of notes:

- Do not use Maven for deployment. Maven is a build tool, it's not suitable for deployments. Write bash scripts and possibly use Docker for deployment automation.
- Do not use LATEST/SNAPSHOT/RELEASE versions - you need to have a deterministic deployment (if it's repeated with the same params it deploys the same artifact).

A sample script that sets a snapshot-like version (so it's possible to upload the artifact to snapshot Maven repo):

```
VERSION=`mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep -v "^\["| grep -v Download`
VERSION=${VERSION/%-SNAPSHOT/} #get rid of -SNAPSHOT if it's there
VERSION="$VERSION-"`date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S"`"-$BUILD_NUMBER"
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=$VERSION
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer , your solve my doubts , now I am using docker to deploy the spring application , I have a simple project and I am interested to learn how to made the deploy correctly in a Continuous delivery. Thanks for all !